# Is slicing a vector faster than copying each element into a new vector?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

Let's say I have a vector of 10 ints and I want to create 2 subvectors each of 5 elements.

Is it faster if I slice the vector like this:

```
vector<int> vec({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
auto x = vec.begin();
vector<int> vec2(x, x+5);
x += 5;
vector<int> vec3(x, x+5);
```

As opposed to this?

```
vector<int> vec({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
vector<int> vec2;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    vec2.push_back(vec[i]);
}
vector<int> vec3;
for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    vec3.push_back(vec[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please post real code.  There is no `push` function for `std::vector`, and the `for` loop conditions are missing / incorrect.

Comment: Fixed now, sorry

Comment: This is as much a misunderstanding of optimization as asking about `i++` and `++i`. Have you measured a performance problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First will be faster, because in the first way `std::vector` will allocate all needed memory in first construction, but in second way with `std::vector<T>::push_back` need to allocate memory and increase the underlying array size which is painful.

Here is a little benchmark: https://quick-bench.com/q/dXoWJhTzYDgNnIPFj-vla4pZ_PU

[image]

Comment: *Second will be faster* -- You cannot know this until you actually compile the code and see what the optimizer will do.  [Sample 1](https://godbolt.org/z/x9EqWM).  [Sample 2](https://godbolt.org/z/j456EG)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, https://quick-bench.com/q/dXoWJhTzYDgNnIPFj-vla4pZ_PU

Comment: A small note: most of the time spent on the second one is reallocating memory. One single allocation with `vector.reserve` reduces most of the time the second one spends: https://quick-bench.com/q/ITw2ZJHv7YyAR7GCyW5Z56yUs7o